# Drug something now key wont turn on my 05 clk320

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, mercedes-benz, ignition-key, clk320

i was driving down the hiway and a trash can flew off bk of a guys truck like a 12 gallon kitchen on, i ran over it and drug it, i exited off and it came out, i then got bk on the hiway and as i was getting bk on, my car cut off with all the engine light on and thermostat light etc, when i turned the key it woul activate car but would not crank, i went to check it today and now it wont let the key turn at all, as if its locked up, I did turn the tire, (wheel) and it still didnt crank, also it wont let me switch gears and the brakes are even tight as ever

Comment: This needs to be put on a ramp and damage inspected - there could be many things causing the issue. Running over a trash can is not usually a good thing.,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Agreeing with @SolarMike here ... this needs some rack time and extensive diagnostics.